# Android appwidget, can i put buttons on it?

Tags: android, android-appwidget

I would like to add twoo buttons on an appwidget, then i would like to set the onclicklistener methods of this.

Is there a way to do it? how?

Answer (score 3):

```
RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getApplicationContext(), R.layout.main_view);

Intent intent = new Intent(context, InputBroadcastReceiver.class); // receiver class
intent.putExtra(EXTRA_ID, id); // some extras

PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);             views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.my_button, pendingIntent);
```

Then override the onReceive method in InputBroadcastReceiver and enjoy your inputs ;)

BroadcastReceivers are explaining [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html).